# How does OrderedDict keep things in Order in Python

Tags: python, dictionary, data-structures, ordereddictionary

I'm curious as to *how* OrderedDict from the collections library keeps key/pair order? I looked around online and couldn't find an answer.

Comment: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/c20c97f6122e7a99e46cbd6c9ac8cb2941a3bf7a/Lib/collections.py#L35

Comment: Thanks, this helps a lot.

Comment: The standard `dict` in Python 3.6 is also ordered, but it's much more efficient.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the source code, it appears to be implemented as a `dict` with a doubly linked list of keys for ordering, as well as another `dict` that maps keys to their position in the list.

- Insertion just adds to the end of the list.
- Deletion uses the second dict to remove an element from the list.
- Iteration iterates over the linked list.

Comment: I guess there's a bit more overhead when using OrderedDict than from the normal dict.